# Battery draining in ASUS TUF FX506

Tags: power-management, battery

I am experiencing a very annoying issue: battery lasts roughly 1h10' on a brand new ASUS TUF FX506.

Have installed TLP and am having the attached tlp-stat output at the bottom. Sorry for the lenghty message, but I think is positive to provide enough information.

I am not an experienced user and don't have the skills to understand what might going wrong in the background.Somehow tweaking the TLP has apparently no effect at all in the battery behavior.

If anybody can point me in the right direction please??

Thanks and regards,

Carlos.

```
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT="1"
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT="4"
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT="powersave"
CPU_HWP_ON_AC="balance_power"
CPU_HWP_ON_BAT=balance_power
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=power
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm min_power"
AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT=15
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT="low"
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC=0
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=0
USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=0
USB_BLACKLIST_PRINTER=1
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

+++ System Info
System         = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. 1.0 TUF Gaming FA506IU_FX506IU
BIOS           = FA506IU.304
Release        = Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Kernel         = 5.3.0-59-generic #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 4 14:58:26 UTC 2020 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-generic root=UUID=7d909dcd-43ed-444a-998a-e3ccc2c875c5 ro quiet splash nomodeset noresume vt.handoff=1
Init system    = systemd v237
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
Last run       = 18:27:04,     29 sec(s) ago
Mode           = battery
Power source   = battery

+++ Processor
CPU model      = AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_driver   = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_governor = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2900000 1700000 1400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost                  = 1

x86_energy_perf_policy: program not installed.

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient       = Y
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.

+++ Temperatures
Fan speed              = (not available)

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     4
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  6000
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  6000
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10

+++ Storage Devices

+++ AHCI Link Power Management (ALPM)
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = med_power_with_dipm

+++ AHCI Host Controller Runtime Power Management
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/ata1/power/control = on

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = powersave

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = on
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

hci0(btusb)                   : bluetooth, not connected
wlp3s0(rtw_pci)               : wifi, connected, power management = on

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 1
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = Y

+++ Runtime Power Management
Device blacklist = (not configured)
Driver blacklist = amdgpu nouveau nvidia radeon (default)

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.1/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.2/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.4/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.0/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.1/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.2/power/control = auto (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control = auto (0x0c0500, SMBus, piix4_smbus)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.3/power/control = auto (0x060100, ISA bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.0/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.1/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.2/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.3/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.4/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.5/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.6/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.7/power/control = auto (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control = on   (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.2/power/control = auto (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.3/power/control = auto (0x0c8000, Serial bus controller [0c80], nvidia-gpu)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control = auto (0x020000, Ethernet controller, r8169)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control = auto (0x028000, Network controller, rtw_pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/power/control = auto (0x010802, Non-Volatile memory controller, nvme)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/power/control = auto (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.1/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.2/power/control = auto (0x108000, Encryption controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.3/power/control = auto (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.4/power/control = auto (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.5/power/control = auto (0x048000, Multimedia controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.6/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/power/control = auto (0x010601, SATA controller, ahci)

+++ USB
Autosuspend         = enabled
Device whitelist    = (not configured)
Device blacklist    = (not configured)
Bluetooth blacklist = disabled
Phone blacklist     = disabled
WWAN blacklist      = enabled

Bus 006 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 005 Device 002 ID 13d3:3548 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- IMC Networks  (btusb)
Bus 005 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 004 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 003 ID 13d3:56a2 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- IMC Networks  (uvcvideo)
Bus 003 Device 002 ID 046d:c05a control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse (usbhid)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = ASUS 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = A32-K55
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full_design             =   4110 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full                    =   3974 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now                     =   3974 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/current_now                    =   2367 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Discharging

Charge                                                      =  100.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   96.7 [%]

+++ Suggestions
* Install smartmontools for disk drive health info
```

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop has (most likely) Nvidia Optimus hybrid graphics and you seem to have installed the proprietary drivers.

I propose two things:

a. enable the TLP PPA to get the latest version ([refer to the docs](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powercon.html#hybrid-graphics)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
```

b. Execute the following steps from the [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powercon.html#hybrid-graphics):

Step 1: Enable Runtime Power Management for GPU drivers

Remove all GPU drivers from the blacklist, leaving only

```
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="mei_me"
```

Hint: for this you must change the config file **/etc/tlp.conf**, remember to remove the leading *#*

Then apply the changed settings with

```
sudo tlp start
```

Anticipated result: the GPU will be suspended (power off) automatically when in idle state.

Step 2a: Switch to the iGPU - Nvidia Optimus with proprietary driver and settings tool

Start nvidia-settings, goto PRIME Profiles, select Intel (Power Saving Mode). Logon again (or reboot).

Result: rendering the screen content is shifted to the iGPU, sending the dGPU to idle state, thus permitting runtime power management to power off the dGPU (see Step 1).

EDIT: Step 2a may be different with an AMD Ryzen CPU. I'd be interested to learn about the difference.